# Excel VBA: Using Checkboxes to select row and paste to different sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to be able to select a checkbox next to a row of information and then click a button to paste to another sheet.  What I have here works but I want to be able to select multiple boxes and paste them to the other sheet with clicking the button once.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
'TO Bid Numbers

    'BID DATE
    If CheckBox1.Value = True Then Sheets("Bidding").Range("B3").Copy Sheets("Bid Numbers").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

    'PROJECT NAME
    If CheckBox1.Value = True Then Sheets("Bidding").Range("C3").Copy Sheets("Bid Numbers").Range("B1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

    'ESTIMATOR
    If CheckBox1.Value = True Then Sheets("Bidding").Range("D3").Copy Sheets("Bid Numbers").Range("C1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

    'OUR PRICE
    If CheckBox1.Value = True Then Sheets("Bidding").Range("E3").Copy Sheets("Bid Numbers").Range("D1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

End Sub
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? If this works for `CheckBox1`, can't you figure out how to make it work for `CheckBox2`, etc?  Also, you could do all your copy/past within an `If` block. there's no need to redundantly do the boolean `If Checkbox1.Value = True` four times :)

Comment: You're only referring to one checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

This works for Form control checkboxes:

Loop through each checkbox on your sheet and see if it's ticked.  If it is then look at the `TopLeftCell` to get the location of the checkbox and add the `EntireRow` to a range that you will eventually copy and paste onto the second sheet.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim chkBx As Shape
    Dim rngToCopy As Range

    For Each chkBx In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes
        If chkBx.Type = 8 Then
            If chkBx.OLEFormat.Object.Value = 1 Then
                If rngToCopy Is Nothing Then
                    Set rngToCopy = chkBx.TopLeftCell.EntireRow
                Else
                    Set rngToCopy = Union(rngToCopy, chkBx.TopLeftCell.EntireRow)
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next chkBx

    rngToCopy.Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")

End Sub
```